# How to organize layout in different screens size

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I got this method that returns either "Desktop","Tablet" or "Mobile" based on screen size.

```
    class Responsive extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget mobile;
  final Widget tablet;
  final Widget desktop;

  const Responsive({
    Key key,
    @required this.mobile,
    this.tablet,
    @required this.desktop,
  }) : super(key: key);

// This size work fine on my design, maybe you need some customization depends on your design

  // This isMobile, isTablet, isDesktop helep us later
  static bool isMobile(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 850;

  static bool isTablet(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 1100 &&
          MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 850;

  static bool isDesktop(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 1100;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size _size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    // If our width is more than 1100 then we consider it a desktop
    if (_size.width >= 1100) {
      return desktop;
    }
    // If width it less then 1100 and more then 850 we consider it as tablet
    else if (_size.width >= 850 && tablet != null) {
      return tablet;
    }
    // Or less then that we called it mobile
    else {
      return mobile;
    }
  }
```

I want to use it to render each time some elements based on the screen size.
For example :
On Desktop: I want to return a Drawer on the left side on the screen using `Expended` with `flex :2` and another widget that takes the rest of the screen on the right.

```
if(Responsive.isDesktop(context))
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: SideMenu(),
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: Text("Im the right side"))

            ],
          ),
```

The widget `SideMenu()` returns a Drawer .

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use width & height in the widget calculate it using **media queries** it automatically calculate the screen height and width then adjust the widget accordingly.